# No page number for pdf appendix in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, appendices

I'm writing my masterthesis and struggle with the pagenumbers of my appendix in the toc. How can the pagenumbers be removed just for the appendixes? The only appendices I have are included pdfs.
It's my first post here, so please let me know, if I did something wrong or didn't gave you enough informations. Thank you!

```
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\begin{document}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{appendix}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
    \includepdf[pages={-last},addtotoc={1,subsection,1,name,sec:name}]{filepath.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the output pdf to not supply its own page numbers for the appendix, or are you wanting the output pdf to remove page numbers that are already present in `filepath.pdf`?

Comment: I just want, that the pagenumber of the pdf is not shown in the toc. 
ChatGPT already gave me a solution (I should have asked ChatGPT first maybe before writing there). 
It gave me: `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}`